# Tree to a list of possible paths (values)

Tags: haskell

Given a tree data structure defined as

```
data Tree = Node Int Tree Tree | Leaf
```

How can one transform it into a list of values along all paths?

For example `Node 1 (Node 2 Leaf Leaf) (Node 3 Leaf Leaf)` should translate to `[[1,2], [1,3]]`.

Answer (score 4):

You have a recursive data structure, so you should expect a recursive solution. The first step in such a solution is to identify the base cases. For this problem, there is the obvious base case: `Leaf`. We probably also want to treat `Node x Leaf Leaf` as a base case to avoid duplicate paths.

Now let's write down the type signature. This should make it clear what our base cases should produce.

```
paths :: Tree -> [[Int]]
```

For `Leaf` the sensible thing to do is return a list containing an empty list since a `Leaf` is representing an empty path.

```
paths Leaf = [[]]
```

For `Node x Leaf Leaf`, we can return a list consisting of a list containing `x`.

```
paths (Node x Leaf Leaf) = [[x]]
```

The next part requires the most thought. We need to consider what to do with the non-base case `Node x left right`. The strategy here is to assume that we have the result of `paths left` and `paths right` and then decide what we need to do with `x`.  We're building paths, so we need to tack `x` onto the front of all the `left` paths and the `right` paths. We also need to combine the two lists into a single list.

```
paths (Node x left right) = map (x:) (paths left ++ paths right)
```

And that's it.  Of course, now you might want to see if there's a more efficient way to implement it, or if there's a common pattern here instead (i.e. can we write this as a fold?).

Comment: This will lead to paths like `[[3,5],[3]]` on `Node 3 (Node 5 Leaf Leaf) Leaf`.

Comment: @Zeta that is exactly what I would expect to get. (also, I think you meant `Node 3 (Node 5 Leaf Leaf) Leaf`)

Comment: Well, it depends on the definition of a _path_ in this context, but usually it's the values that are encountered to the way to a leaf (in the sense that it doesn't have any child nodes). In the example above, `Node 3` isn't a leaf, since it has a child node, therefore it shouldn't come up as the last node in a path. But again, that depends on the definition of a path. But it's trivial to fix either way.

Comment: Start at the root and take the right branch. The path is `[3]`. If we can't count edges that end at a `Leaf` then `Node 3 Leaf Leaf` wouldn't define any path.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here is very simple, so for a Tree structure such as the one you provided, if we have:

```
data Tree = Node Int Tree Tree | Leaf
```

We would need a nested function within our function, basically a function which returns a list from a branch, this way we can have the first argument of the Tree (the trunk or initial value) separated from values of either of the branches, but I'm sure there is a more efficient implementation, so here it is:

```
traverse :: Tree a -> [[Int]] -- Do not use "a" in the return type 
traverse Leaf = [[]]
traverse (Node value left right) = [value] ++ treeToList left : [value] ++ treeToList right : []
 where treeToList Leaf = []
       treeToList (Node a left right) = [a] ++ treeToList left ++ treeToList right
```

returns

```
> traverse (Node 2 (Node 3 Leaf Leaf) (Node 4 Leaf Leaf))
> [[2,3],[2,4]]
```

Be careful with the return type as **Tree a** denotes that a is polymorphic but the constructor **Node** takes only values of type **Int**, denoting the returned list can only be of type Int.